# Azure SQL Database - Rebuild Index With Resumable Not Working

Tags: t-sql, azure-sql-database

I'm running an index maintenance routine against a number of Azure SQL databases. I'm using the following query to get a list of indexes to Reorganize or Rebuild in each database:

```
Declare @ReorgThreshold int = 5
Declare @RebuildThreshold int = 30
Declare @MinPageCount int = 100

SELECT x.TableName, x.IndexName, x.PercentFragmentation, 
        CASE WHEN x.PercentFragmentation < @RebuildThreshold THEN 'Reorganize' ELSE 'Rebuild' END as ActionType
  FROM
    (SELECT OBJECT_NAME(PS.object_id) AS TableName, I.name AS IndexName, IPS.avg_fragmentation_in_percent as PercentFragmentation
      FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats as PS INNER JOIN 
         sys.indexes  as I ON PS.object_id = I.object_id AND PS.index_id = I.index_id AND I.type in (1/*Clustered index*/,2/*NonClustered index*/) CROSS APPLY 
         sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(), ps.object_id, ps.index_id, null, 'LIMITED') as IPS
     WHERE IPS.index_id < 1000 -- no xml, columstore, or spatial indexes
         AND IPS.avg_fragmentation_in_percent > @ReorgThreshold 
         AND IPS.page_count >= @MinPageCount) as x
```

And then I'm executing ALTER INDEX statements against each of the indexes returned. If the action is "Rebuild", this is the SQL I'm running:

```
ALTER INDEX PK_My_Table ON dbo.My_Table 
REBUILD WITH (ONLINE = ON , MAXDOP = 1, RESUMABLE = ON)
```

Which executes successfully but doesn't seem to do anything. If I run the top query again, the index is still listed there with the same level of fragmentation. If I remove "RESUMABLE = ON" from the ALTER INDEX statement, the index actually appears to get rebuilt, and the top query won't return it.

I thought perhaps it was just running in the background, but selecting from sys.index_resumable_operations returns nothing. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

After having feedback from a Microsoft Senior PM in charge of the RESUMABLE option for maintaining indexes on Azure SQL Database and SQL Server, allow me to update my answer. He mentioned that the specific issue you are facing is caused by the fact that currently Microsoft does not support resumable rebuild operations for a "primary key" constraint. He mentioned his team has this feature on plans but could not give us a timeline.

He promised Microsoft will update current documentation to reflect above limitation.

Additionally, he mentioned that "currently there is a soft limit of rows around 300 K, below which index fragmentation may get worst during index rebuild with resumable index. In such case, for now, we recommend not to use the RESUMABLE option." He wants you to know that they are working on this issue and will fix it soon.

About online index operations he said is supported on all tiers of Azure SQL Database, but on SQL Server on-premises is only supported on Enterprise Edition.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Alberto. Are you sure that is true? I haven't seen that documented anywhere. But in any event all of my databases are in the "Elastic Premium" pricing tier (i.e. Premium tier in an elastic pool).

Comment: Online index defragmentation and Columnstore have always been limited to SQL Enterprise Edition. Columstore is documented as Premium tier limited feature but online indexes have not been documented. I will share your thread with Microsoft engineers and let you know. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Hi Brian! I updated my answer with all the feedback I got from a Microsoft PM. Thank you for bringing this question to the table and for allowing me to correct my mistake about online operations in Azure SQL Database.

Comment: Hi Brian, The same Microsoft manager is asking a few questions. I hope you can helps answer them: How big is the customer table (how many rows) ?
•What is the table schema including all indexes and a primary key ?
•What is the fragmentation % before executing the statement and after  ( with RESUMABLE)
•What is the fragmentation % before executing the statement and after  ( with ONLINE only)

Comment: Thanks again, Alberto. Regarding some of your questions - I have around 100 databases in 2 Elastic Pools, all of which are on the Elastic Premium pricing tier. The tables range in size as does the index fragmentation. But one example, the table is around 20K rows and the fragmentation is over 90%. The index that I'm trying to rebuild on that table is a non-clustered index. The primary key for the table is not indexed, but is an included column So is that what you mean by "rebuild operations on a primary key constraint"?

Comment: Hi Brian, thank you for your patience. Here is the answer provided by the Senior Microsoft Manager in charge of this feature: "currently there is a soft limit of rows around 300 K, below which  index fragmentation may get worst  during index rebuild with resumable index. In such case, for now,  we recommend not to use the RESUMABLE option. " . He wants  you to know that they are working on this issue and will fix it soon.

Comment: Thank you Alberto for continuing to follow up on this. That sure is strange behavior. FYI, I couldn't find any difference between rebuilding indexes where a primary key was an indexed column, included column, or not in the index at all, so maybe that part was a bit of a red herring?

Comment: You did not find any difference ... Let me share that with them. Thank you for contributing to fix this issue.

Comment: I know this may be a lot of work for you, but can you please answer the following question and send it to an email to resumableidxpreview@microsoft.com with CC to alberto_morillo@hotmail.com: Table definition ( exact table schema)
2.  Index definition (exact index schema)
3.  Current number of rows in the table
4.The exact ALTER INDEX command(s) that is being executed
5.Output from  sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats  before and alter the ALTER INDEX operation
6.It would be good to see it WITH ONLINE=ON w/o RESUMABLE and with RESUMABLE
Thank you in advance.